# Weird NullPointerException in a place I don't expect it:

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

So the deal is like this, I released an application to Store yesterday, And I'm getting a lot on null pointer exceptions in my `ArrayAdapter`:

**Adapter:**

```
public class NewVenuesListRecyclingAdapterWithVenueObjects extends ArrayAdapter<Venue>
{   
....
public NewVenuesListRecyclingAdapterWithVenueObjects(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Venue> items) 
{
....
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder holder;
    View currentView = convertView;

    if(null == currentView)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ....
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder)currentView.getTag();
    }

    ....
    if (UserLocation.instance.getLastKnownLocation() == null) {
        holder.venueDistance.setText("");
        ((ViewGroup) currentView).requestLayout();
    } else {
        // cups#202: `venueDistance` might be null in case we recycle a list item
        // this is not really a fix, but should relatively okay (the distance will just not appear).
        if (venuesList.get(position).getDistance() != 0.0f) {
            holder.venueDistance.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.venueDistanceUnit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if(FileAccessUtil.instance.getStringProperty(Consts.DISTANCE_UNIT).equals(Consts.DISTANCE_UNIT_KILOMETER))
            {
                holder.venueDistance.setText(formatDistanceKilometer(activity, venuesList.get(position).getDistance()));
                holder.venueDistanceUnit.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.distance_km));
                CupsLog.d(TAG, "chosen distance unit is km");

            }
            else if(FileAccessUtil.instance.getStringProperty(Consts.DISTANCE_UNIT).equals(Consts.DISTANCE_UNIT_MILE))
            {
                holder.venueDistance.setText(formatDistanceMiles(activity, venuesList.get(position).getDistance()));
                holder.venueDistanceUnit.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.distance_mile));
                CupsLog.d(TAG, "chosen distance unit is mile");
            }
        }
    }
    return currentView;
}

static class ViewHolder 
{
     TextView venueName;
     TextView venueAddress;
     TextView venueDistance;
     TextView venueDistanceUnit;
     ImageView venueImage;
     ImageView venuebackImage;
     ImageView venueMapIcon;
     ImageView venueFavoriteIcon;
     ProgressBar spinner;
 }
}
```

The line that give me the exceptions is this:

```
if(FileAccessUtil.instance.getStringProperty(Consts.DISTANCE_UNIT).equals(Consts.DISTANCE_UNIT_KILOMETER))
```

This line determins if the user want to display distnace in kilometers or miles based on his choice in the settings page, `FileAccessUtil` is a helper class that among other has those methods:

```
public void init(Context context) {
    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Consts.PREFERENCSE_FILE_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public String getStringProperty(String key) {
    String res = null;
    if (sharedPreferences != null) {
        res = sharedPreferences.getString(key, null);
    }
    return res;
}

public void setStringProperty(String key, String value) {
    if (sharedPreferences != null) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
        CupsLog.i(TAG, "Set " + key + " property = " + value);
    }
}
```

The final peace of the passel is that I set this property in my `Application` class:

```
public class App extends Application 
{
....

    public void onCreate() 
    {
        super.onCreate();
        appObjInstance = this;

        FileAccessUtil.instance.init(this);
        if (FileAccessUtil.instance.getStringProperty(Consts.DISTANCE_UNIT) == null)
        {
            FileAccessUtil.instance.setStringProperty(Consts.DISTANCE_UNIT, Consts.DISTANCE_UNIT_KILOMETER);
        }
        ....
    }
}
```

I could ofcourse check for null before getting the preference but I wanted to avoid this check inside of the adapter that will run for each view in the `ListView`.

Does some one knows what could be the problem?

Comment: `FileAccessUtil.instance` is `null`? You never assign it in the code you showed. Why not debug and see what is `null`?

Comment: @m0skit0, because I don't encounter this issue... my users do... I can't debug a problem I don't see... I'm not getting this exception, but a lot of my users do.

Comment: Then turn on logcat, add a couple of logs for the values, and capture the stacktrace from the users.

Comment: @m0skit0, what do you mean by turn on logcat? can I turn it off? and that exactly how I see the problem... I'm catching the stacktrace using crashlytics platform..

Comment: Is there any chance you call `FileAccessUtil.instance.setStringProperty(Consts.DISTANCE_UNIT, null);` anywhere in code? I would add a log in the `setStringProperty` method to test for this.

Comment: @njzk2, there is a log in setStringProperty, and I never set this parameter to null...because I always need it to have a value.

Comment: At a guess: you say "This line determins if the user want to display distnace in kilometers or miles based on his choice in the settings page" - I'd look at the settings page

Comment: @TonyWilk, but I'm settings Kilometers as a default value... in the application class (that for my knowledge start before any of the activities). So it should be initialized even if the user didn't choose any setting

Comment: Your first step is to check what exactly is null. Add some logs with the object values to see.

Comment: @EmilAdz : obviously, either `FileAccessUtil.instance` or `FileAccessUtil.instance.getString...` is null. So `it should be initialized` is irrelevant here (and wrong, too). There is something that removes the value from the properties, or your instance becomes null at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to write code like this:

```
if(FileAccessUtil.instance.getStringProperty(Consts.DISTANCE_UNIT).equals(Consts.DISTANCE_UNIT_KILOMETER))
```

Then you need to make sure that `getStringProperty(...)` can never return `null`:

```
public String getStringProperty(String key) {
    String res = "";
    if (sharedPreferences != null) {
        res = sharedPreferences.getString(key, null);
    }
    return res;
}
```

The problem is that, while you expect the `Consts.DISTANCE_UNIT` to be present in the user's setup (and I believe you when you say the issue doesn't happen for you, probably because it *is* in your setup), it is not, in fact there. Perhaps the root problem is in your intallation, who knows? But I suspect you should modify `getStringProperty(...)` to return an empty string if no value can be located.

HTH

Comment: **AND** `FileAccessUtil.instance` is also never null.

Comment: @m0skit0, FileAccessUtil.instance can't be null because it writen like this: public static final FileAccessUtil instance = new FileAccessUtil();

Comment: My best guess is that at some point sharedPreferences becomes Null (usually when application not used a lot of time) and the getStringPropery returns null. I will check suggestion @J Steven Perry

Comment: @EmilAdz So I have to guess that you wrote `public static final FileAccessUtil instance = new FileAccessUtil();`? Cool.